# Почему не исчезает полоса горизонтальной прокрутки

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Я уже поставил для `<body>`:

```
@media  only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

но это не действует. Вот ссылка на [сайт](http://triperza.by/). Справа всегда остаётся пространство. Как его убрать?
Прикладываю скрин с `overflow:hidden`.

[image: скриншот]

Comment: прокрутка у вас по вертикали `overflow-y:hidden;`

Comment: @AndreyFedorov это не пропадает даже если я обе оси скрываю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стиль `#footer-info .wrap{width: 900px}` на 395 строке все портит.

В таких ситуациях обычно помогает удаление кусков сайта до определения проблемного.

Comment: Я сбросил все врапы .wrap
 {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
 }

Comment: Не сбросили, #footer-info .wrap перебивает ваш .wrap